# Validation rich text

Tags: validation, validation-rule, richtextarea

I have a rich text field. How do I want to make it compulsory for users to insert an image? I already make the field compulsory, but if I insert the image only, it still considers null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use standard validation to check if rich text field has an image or no. Kindly review Idea link [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DnOaAAK) and Rich text fields that contain images, the image source tag counts against the character limit.  Would recommend to review  Rich text field [limitations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_rich_text_area_limitations.htm&type=0).

As an alternate approach, You would need to use apex trigger to have validation on image on rich text field.  Check sample example [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/128494/validation-rule-on-rich-text-area-field).

Thanks

Comment: Solved. Thank you for helping me! Have a good day :-)